# Отличия while от do while

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, while

не подскажите почему не работает при **while** **(num_1!=0)**, а при **do while** всё нормально?

Я думал что while проверяет в начале, а do while в конце, но теперь запутался можете подсказать где именно они проверяют условие(заранее спасибо)?

ЗАДАЧА:
Напишите программу, которая в последовательности натуральных чисел определяет определяет сумму всех чисел, кратных 6 и оканчивающихся на 4. Программа получает на вход натуральные числа, количество введённых чисел неизвестно, последовательность чисел заканчивается числом 0 (0 — признак окончания ввода, не входит в последовательность). Количество чисел не превышает 1000. Введённые числа не превышают 30 000. Программа должна вывести одно число: сумму всех чисел, кратных 6 и оканчивающихся на 4.

Пример работы программы:

Входные данные:14, 24, 144, 22, 12, 0.

Выходные данные: 168

МОЯ ПРОГА (рабочая):

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int num_1;
int sum;
int shit;


void main()
{
  do
  {
    cout << "Please enter number: ";
    cin >> num_1;

    if (num_1 % 6 == 0)
    {
        if (num_1 % 10 == 4) sum += num_1;
    }
} 
while (num_1!=0);

cout << "\n"<<"\n"<<"The sum of all numbers matching the condition: "<< sum<<"\n";
}
```

НЕ РАБОЧАЯ:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int num_1;
int sum;
int shit;


void main()
{


while (num_1!=0);
{
    cout << "Please enter number: ";
    cin >> num_1;

    if (num_1 % 6 == 0)
    {
        if (num_1 % 10 == 4) sum += num_1;
    }
} 
cout << "\n"<<"\n"<<"The sum of all numbers matching the condition: "<< sum<<"\n";
}
```

Comment: Вы бы инициализировали num_1 чем-то ненулевым, а? Сейчас он, как глобальная переменная, нулевой! И цикл не выполняется ни разу...

Answer (score 0):

Так и есть - while в начале, а do..while   в конце. Если есть что проверять. В вашем while проверять нечего, потому что num_1 неинициализирована.

Или (по слухам) в последних версиях языка равна по умолчанию нулю.

Comment: Стандарт : `If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized
explicitly, then it is initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero`

Comment: Да, и это не в последних версиях, а во всех.

Comment: @Croessmah ок, а в С там мусор, если не инициализировать?

Comment: Я про Си и говорил : https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/initialization @Эникейщик

Comment: Это же глобальная переменная, она 0!

Comment: @Эникейщик Вот я и не понимал почеиу программа при исполнении просто while писала мне cout << "Please enter number: ";